# How to send cart data in hidden field and fetch it in codeigniter controller

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, controller, hidden

I am using codeigniter cart library and I want to get data from cart and pass it to controller via hidden field
following is my cart array

```
$cart = $this->cart->contents();
```

i have added three item in cart and following is var_dump() info

```
array(3) { ["d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820"]=> array(6) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "d3d9446802a44259755d38e6d163e820" ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(4) "1200" ["name"]=> string(11) "soup item 1" ["subtotal"]=> int(1200) } ["c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39"]=> array(6) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39" ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(4) "1400" ["name"]=> string(11) "soup item 2" ["subtotal"]=> int(1400) } ["aab3238922bcc25a6f606eb525ffdc56"]=> array(6) { ["rowid"]=> string(32) "aab3238922bcc25a6f606eb525ffdc56" ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> string(3) "800" ["name"]=> string(11) "soup item 3" ["subtotal"]=> int(800) } }
```

i have extract id, name, qty and price from cart and insert into hidden field,

```
<form action="http://localhost/food4u/site/order_now" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="orderuserid">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="order_restid">
            <input type="hidden" value="238" name="orderDcharges">
            <input type="hidden" value="578" name="ordergst">
            <input type="hidden" value="3400" name="ordersubtotal">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="orderPmethod">

                                 <input type="hidden" value="10" name="cartitemid[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="soup item 1" name="cartitemname[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="cartitemqty[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="1200" name="cartitemprice[]">
                                     <input type="hidden" value="13" name="cartitemid[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="soup item 2" name="cartitemname[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="cartitemqty[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="1400" name="cartitemprice[]">
                                     <input type="hidden" value="14" name="cartitemid[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="soup item 3" name="cartitemname[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="cartitemqty[]">
                 <input type="hidden" value="800" name="cartitemprice[]">
```

-->                
                
and in my controller i get these hidden field value like this

```
            $cartitemid = $this->input->post('cartitemid');
        $cartitemname = $this->input->post('cartitemname');
        $cartitemqty = $this->input->post('cartitemqty');
        $cartitemprice = $this->input->post('cartitemprice');

        print_r($cartitemid).'<br />';
        print_r($cartitemname).'<br />';
        print_r($cartitemqty).'<br />';
        print_r($cartitemprice).'<br />';
        exit;
```

and it will give me result

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 ) Array ( [0] => soup item 1 [1] => soup item 2 [2] => soup item 3 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1200 [1] => 1400 [2] => 800 )
```

and i want to insert this in only one table

```
$data = array(
                'Iem_Id' => ???,
                'Item_Name' => ???,
                'Item_Qty' => ???,
                'Item_Price' => ???,
                );
```

i want to insert all above data in one table please guide me

Comment: you may use sessions in this matter, or create (generate) hidden inputs for every array key

Comment: i have to send four array in hidden field i.e. id, qty, name and price and get them in controller by using foreach but i want to send all these four to my model so that they can insert into one table, please guide me how to pass these four foreach into model

Comment: Please see this http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7 it guides you in pure PHP how to store arrays in session, but read this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html to see how it is all done in CodeIgniter.

Comment: i am already using codeigniter cart library i dont need to store it in session I want to insert them in table

Comment: oh I see, so already have your data in right controller and you just want it to insert in table? If this is the problem I'll gladly help you out. please edit your Q and post whatever `var_dump($this->cart->contents());` displays (while cart has at least 2 items in it) thanks

Comment: now I see the whole problem, let me work on it.

Comment: added/edited answer to your Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
foreach($cartitemid as $key => $cartItem) {
    $data = array(
        'Iem_Id' => $cartItem,
        'Item_Name' => $cartitemname[$key],
        'Item_Qty' => $cartitemqty[$key],
        'Item_Price' => $cartitemprice[$key],
    );
    var_dump($data);
    echo "<br>";
    //$this->db->insert('table', $data);
    unset($data);
}

unset($cartItemId);
unset($key);
```